# Two inner joins in one statement produce 0 result

Tags: mysql

When running multiple inner joins I get zero results

The code is listed below:

```
SELECT doubles_ladder.*, players.*
from doubles_ladder
  JOIN players on doubles_ladder.player_number = players.Player_number
  JOIN players AS play ON doubles_ladder.player_number2 = players.Player_number
```

I know that there is information in both of tables which is odd that it isn't producing results.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the alias you set for the second join table (`play`).
I would change in the following:

```sql
    SELECT doubles_ladder.*, player1.*, player2.*
    FROM doubles_ladder
        INNER JOIN players AS player1
            ON (doubles_ladder.player_number = player1.Player_number)
        INNER JOIN players AS player2
            ON (doubles_ladder.player_number2 = player2.Player_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting for results where `doubles_ladder.player_number = players.Player_number` and `doubles_ladder.player_number2 = players.Player_number`.  All such rows have `doubles_ladder.player_number = doubles_ladder.player_number2`.  That doesn't appear to be what you intended, and it seems plausible that there would not be any such results.

I think you want this, instead:

```sql
SELECT doubles_ladder.*, players.*
from doubles_ladder
  JOIN players on doubles_ladder.player_number = players.Player_number
  JOIN players AS play ON doubles_ladder.player_number2 = play.Player_number
```

Comment: So if I do this: 

` SELECT doubles_ladder.team_number, doubles_ladder.player_number, doubles_ladder.player_number2, players.Player_number, players.Player_name from doubles_ladder INNER JOIN players on doubles_ladder.player_number = players.Player_number INNER JOIN players AS play ON doubles_ladder.player_number2 = play.Player_number WHERE doubles_ladder.team_number = 2006 `

Then how come it only produces one name for two player numbers?

BTW the query above worked, I just changed it a little to meet my specific criteria.

Comment: Because that query selects only one player name, @golffor1.  Add `play.Player_name` to the selection list if you want that to be included in the results as well.